# Local error when using crop from raster package

Tags: r, crop, raster, r-raster

I imported raster files into `R` (Landsat TM-5 surface reflectance products). Now I want to crop these rasters using boundaries of my test region (also raster file).
Importing went well without any mistakes. But when I tried to use crop function I've got an error message: `Error in .local(.Object, ...)` :

> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype =
>   "RasterLayer",  :    Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this
>   file. (file does not exist).

I cannot figure out what the problem is. I have tried, but the code run unsuccessfully. The code and the error are these:

```
red0610=raster("LT51710242010172MOR00_sr_band3.tif")
nir0610=raster("LT51710242010172MOR00_sr_band4.tif")
red0910=raster("LT51720242010259MOR00_sr_band3.tif")
nir0910=raster("LT51720242010259MOR00_sr_band4.tif")
testfields=raster("testfields.tif")
red0610=crop(testfields,red0610)
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

Imported files located in working directory. I would be very greatful for any help.

Comment: Impossible to reproduce but the error message states `file does not exist` so you might want to make sure you're reading in the correct folder.

Comment: Looks like your file path is wrong.

Comment: I wonder why my path is wrong. All files are located in one folder which I set as working directory. I imported them without problem, but I can't work with them. When I type the name of the imported file, R shows the information (coordinate system, resolutiuon, etc.). But when I am trying to cut or resample, I've got an error message. In R-studio Environmet they are shown as Formal Class Rasterlayer. I am frustrated.

Comment: I am still confused by the error message. At what line does the error occur? This error message usually points to the functions `raster()` or `stack()`, more precisely when the filepath is wrong. Can you please double check if both rasters `red0610` and `testfields` are properly loaded into R (maybe show the output when you call these objects).

Comment: It should not be a problem, but you are using the same name in your crop function.  Try `red0610_temp <- crop(testfields,red0610)`  sometimes the raster packages has weird behaviour with is temporary files.  Also, stop working with `setwd()` and write the full path instead.

Comment: Other option: what is your working directory?  Can you do `red0610+nir0610`? What is your `rasterOptions` tmpdir?  Do you have writing rights?

Comment: Actually, all perfectly worked on my laptop at home. I saved all I did as Workspace and when I opened it on my computer at work everything was fine.